# Inheritance as a specialization

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class called Book with fields such as title, type etc. I also have a class called Library that manages books.

Library has methods that:

- Add a copy of a book on a shelf
- Move a copy of a book from a shelf to another

How Can I manage the fact of the copy of the book?

One solution is create a subclass of Book, i.e. BookCopy.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You're making this too complicated.  The concept of a book is a *class.* Copies of the book are *instances*  of the class.  Add enough fields to the class to allow you to distinguish one *instance* of a book from another.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily helpful to translate real-world concepts too directly into an object model. In the real world, a “book” and a “copy of a book” seem to be the same thing. Perhaps we should create a book class, and copies are instances of that class? No.

It seems a “book” and a “copy of a book” are *different* concepts in your problem domain. One book can have many copies. Both concepts should be represented in your object model. It might then be sensible to create two different classes. For example:

```java
// represent an abstract published book
class Book {
  String author;
  String title;
  Date publication;
  ISBN isbn;
}

// represent a copy of a book that can be lent out
class BookCopy {
  Book book;
  CatalogNumber id;
  Optional<User> currentlyLentOutTo;
  int shelf;
}
```

Why not use inheritance? If you use inheritance, then the book copy would contain all book fields directly. We then cannot answer questions such as “how many copies do we have of this book” without comparing all object contents. Representing different concepts as different classes is usually better.

OOP best practices strongly discourage overuse of inheritance. It turns out, inheritance is often the problem and not the solution. As a rough guideline: inheritance tends to be misused when you want to inherit fields or method implementations. Inheritance tends to be applied correctly when you want to inherit an interface, in order to enable polymorphism: you have a bunch of different things that you want to use through the same interface. This happens fairly often, but most of the time you don't need polymorphism, and therefore don't need inheritance.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, inheritence isn't a solution. This solution seems have more sense

Comment: I understand what you are saying here, but I think what the OP really needs is a record that represents a *book transaction,* not a copy of a book.  Otherwise, you don't keep any history of who you lent the book out to.  Your assertion that a class *instance* cannot represent a book copy is demonstrably false.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My assertion is that “book = class, copy = instance of book” is a problematic model, and “book = instance, copy = instance of different class” is probably better. If the problem domain has transactions, then modelling those transactions seems sensible. I can't find that in the question, though.

Comment: If by "book" you mean "the product of an author" and not "something you keep in a library and loan out," then yes, you're right.  Whether or not the OP actually needs that distinction is an open question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a console application, you can structure the book class to have attribute, copies. 
If you need a visual representation of this data, then a list|array of Book may work?

I don't think creating BookCopy creates any value towards re-usability.

Answer (score 1):

In the terms that a librarian uses, a "copy of a book" is one of the possibly several physical books that have the same author,title,etc.

In OO terms a "copy of a book" would refer to an instance of the Book class, where it is possible that there are several instances with the same author,title,etc.

If you need to be able to tell these instances with the same author,title,etc. apart, you can add an id property to your Book class that is unique for every instance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an abstract book (with author, title, contents etc.) and a physical book (a book printed on paper, bound in leather, cardboard etc.)

I'd have a class AbstractBook, which you could use within the library catalogue for example (because the library catalogue doesn't contain physical books), and a class PhysicalBook, which would contain a reference to an AbstractBook. A PhysicalBook (printed on paper) is not an AbstractBook, so it shouldn't be a subclass.

A PhysicalBook would also have properties like purchase price, where purchased, physical state (brand new, almost new, damaged, falling apart), whether the book is on loan, and so on.

If you actually write code to be used by a real world library, where people take these things seriously, you might also have a class "BookEdition" where multiple editions can have the same abstract book, but different dates of printing, ISBN numbers and so on. And a translation of a book could be considered the same or a different book.

Answer (score 0):

> Add a copy of a book on a shelf

```
shelfTop.add(bookOldManAndTheSea);
```

> Move a copy of a book from a shelf to another

```
shelfTop.remove(bookOldManAndTheSea);
shelfBottom.add(bookOldManAndTheSea);
```

This is one of those things that's very simple if you break it down the right way.

> One solution is create a subclass of Book, i.e. BookCopy.

Huh?

Exactly what behavior does a `BookCopy` have that `Book` doesn't? Are reprints discounted in your library? This doesn't seem to have much to do with your add / move concerns. I'm not sure where you're going with this line of thought but it doesn't appear to be anywhere good.

Comment: `Exactly what behavior does a BookCopy have that Book doesn't?` Depends on what the OP means by "book."